# Group by and retain original fields

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I see in mongodb aggregations, specially in `$group` we can use accumulator to create new fields. But i want the old keys

Suppose i have this data

```
[
   { name: "My Plan 101", billingCycle: 'day', amount: 1, credits: 100, price: 7 },
   { name: "My Plan 102", billingCycle: 'day', amount: 1, credits: 150, price: 10 },
   { name: "My Plan 103", billingCycle: 'day', amount: 2, credits: 150, price: 15 },
   { name: "My Plan 104", billingCycle: 'month', amount: 3, credits: 150, price: 15 },
   { name: "My Plan 105", billingCycle: 'month', amount: 3, credits: 200, price: 20 },
]
```

Then the aggregation should be like

```
[
    'day': { 
        '1': [{ name: 'My Plan 101' }, { name: 'My Plan 102' }],
        '2': [{ name: 'My Plan 103' }]
    },
    'month': {
        '3': [{ name: 'My Plan 104' }, { name: 'My Plan 105' }]
    }
]
```

Comment: your expected result is not a valid json, you cannot get an object as key.

Comment: @matthPen I have updated the JSON structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried a lot with mongodb aggregation but couldn't solve it so I used lodash for this.

```
let plans = await Plan.find()
plans = _.groupBy(plans, 'billingCycle');

for (const billingCyle in plans) {
  let $plans = plans[billingCyle];
  plans[billingCyle] = _.groupBy($plans, "amount")
}
console.log(plans)
```

The above snipped has solved my problem